# If $\|f(x,y) \| > \|(x,y)\|^{2}$ for all $(x,y)$ then do we have a point $(x_{0}, y_{0})$ where $\vert det(Df(x_{0},y_{0})) \vert >M$.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I was wondering if the following was true:

> Given $f: \mathbb{R}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2}$, a differentiable function where $\|f(x,y) \| > \|(x,y)\|^{2}$ for all $(x,y)$, then given any $M \in \mathbb{R}$ does there exists a point $(x_{0}, y_{0})$ where $\vert det(Df(x_{0},y_{0}) \vert >M$?

There is a $\mathbb{R}$ analogue of this which is true via the mean-value theorem, I however do not see how the mean value property helps in this case. The analogue is below:

If $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a differentiable function and $f(x)> x^{2}$ for all $x$, then given any $M \in \mathbb{R}$ there is an $x_{0}$ such that $\vert f'(x_{0}) \vert > M$.

We have as an application of the mean value theorem for any $x_{1}> x_{2}$, that there exists an $x_{0}$ where 
\begin{align*}
\vert f'(x_{0}) &= \frac{\vert(f(x_{1})-f(x_{2}) \vert}{\vert x_{1}-x_{2} \vert} \\
&> \frac{ \vert f(x_{1}) \vert - \vert f(x_{2}) \vert }{x_{1}-x_{0}} \\
&> \frac{x_{1}^{2} -x_{1}^{2}}{x_{1}-x_{2}} \\
&= x_{2}+x_{1}
\end{align*}
The result then follows if we choose $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$ to where $x_{1} + x_{2}> M$.

Comment: $Df(x_{0},y_{0})$ should be the Jacobian at the point $(x_{0},y_{0})$

Comment: can you link to the analogue in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Sure, I made an edit above.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(x,y)=  (x^2+y^2+1 \hskip 2pt ; \hskip 2pt 0)$, then $\det Df=0$.